# Is using If, ElseIf, ElseIf better than using If, If, If?

Tags: if-statement

Is there really any difference between using

```
If(this)
{
}
Else If(that)
{
}
Else
{
}
```

or using,

```
If(this)
{
}
If(that)
{
}
Else
{
}
```

?
Does one execute any faster? Does the compiler or architecture make any difference?

Comment: this is basic programming question , you find answer in c book 4 chapter

Comment: Have you tried running your code?

Comment: "execute any faster" is the *LAST* thing you should be worrying about in deciding which construct to use. The #1 consideration is correctness - they do different things, as the many excellent answers below explain, so choose the one that gives the right answer. #2 is clarity: when there are two valid options, choose whichever is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Suppose I said: "If the store carries Coke, buy me a Coke. If they carry Pepsi, buy me a Pepsi. If they carry Mountain Dew, buy me a Mountain Dew." Now suppose the store carries all three sodas. What should you buy? According to what I logically asked: all three. The word "else" makes a **big** difference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's the huge difference that the contents of the `this`-block and the `that`-block can *both* be executed in the second form, whereas the first form allows at most one of those to be executed.

Compare these two Python snippets:

```
x = 10

if x > 5:
    print "x larger than 5"
elif x > 1:
    print "x larger than 1"
else:
    print "x not larger than 1"

# output: x larger than 5
```

and

```
x = 10

if x > 5:
    print "x larger than 5"
if x > 1:  # not using else-if anymore!
    print "x larger than 1"
else:
    print "x not larger than 1"

# output line 1: x larger than 5
# output line 2: x larger than 1
```

As others have mentioned, you generally shouldn't be concerned about performance between these variations so much as you should be concerned about *correctness*.  However, since you asked... all else being equal, the second form will be slower because the second conditional *must* be evaluated.

But unless you have determined that code written in this form is a bottleneck, it's not really worth your effort to even *think* about optimizing it.  In switching from the first form to the second, you give up the jump out of the first if-statement and get back a forced evaluation of the second condition.  Depending on the language, that's *probably* an extremely negligible difference.

Comment: Right, both will be observationally equivalent only is `this`and `that` are mutually exclusive.
As a side note, there might be a performance impact, due to how the compiler can generate code for both. For a language such as [lisaac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisaac), where `if` blocks are compiled using dispatch tables if possible, using `else if` can lead to performance improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in your first example, if this evaluates to true and that evaluates to true, only the first code block will be executed, whereas in the second example, they both will.

They are not equivalent

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

In the First case: control-flow will only check the next condition if the current condition fails but in the second case it will check all conditions that come across.

In first case Else part will only be executed if all previous conditions fails to be true. and in the second case only if the last If condition fails.

Comment: In the second case, the Else statement could be evaluated if the first if is true and the second is false.

Answer (score 1):

it makes a difference.

in case "this" and "that" are both true, both part of code will result something else.

Answer (score 0):

**In first code.** 
it will check **IF**, if **this** is true then execute its body, 
if false then will 
check **ELSEIF** if **that** is true that execute its body,
if false then will
execute body of else.

**Second code**
it will check **IF**, if **this** is true then execute its body, 
if false do nothing.
check 2nd **IF** if **that** is true that execute its body,
if false then will
execute body of else.